# No qualifying bean of my type while injecting

Tags: java, mysql, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc

I'm trying to make **REST spring application** with **two** databases: *MySQL* and *MongoDB*. I've problem with repositories in spring data. I need one repository for JPA and one for MongoDB. I don't want to separate them because then I'll need to separate me serbices.

**Here is [link](https://github.com/javaWorkspace/Campus/tree/injectingMongoDB) on this project.**

There are 8 test classes. 4 for nosql database and 4 for relational. Now tests for relational database works. If you'll change `CrudRepository` on `MongoRepository` in `com.javaworkspace.repositories` will work nosql database tests.

Hierarchically `MongoRepository` extends from `CrudRepository`, but when I execute this code I'm getting exceprion like this :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.javaworkspace.repositories.MarkRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: 
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'markServiceImpl': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.javaworkspace.repositories.MarkRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.annotation.Resource(shareable=true, lookup=, name=, description=, authenticationType=CONTAINER, type=class java.lang.Object, mappedName=)}
```

Comment: in your `@Enable*Respositories`, provide the package name where the repos are located. you have to isolate them into different packages for this to work.. `@EnableMongoRespositories(value = {"com.javaworkspace.mongo"})`

Comment: But then I need to copypaste my Service classes to work with different repositories.

Comment: you can still keep all the service classes in one package

Comment: But then I need to choose one between nosql or relational repository in service. You can see it on [photo](https://pp.vk.me/c836424/v836424062/e03f/zWzWqnWP9Tw.jpg)

Comment: sry can't open the link.. but you can still autowire both repos to your service class..

Comment: [photo](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bym3b2_NWfPDSl9BREJHVVNvX28). I wants to use one repository for nosql and relational databases

Comment: but you will have separate configurations for Mongo and Relational dont you?

Comment: yes, I have. They are in `com.javaworkspace.configuration.relational` and `com.javaworkspace.configuration.nosql`